# XMLParsing using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am having the sample XMLdata in the below format.Out of which I want to extract the values of IChannelID,StartTime,EndTime,Reading Value using PIG.
I tried using XMLLoader(piggynank.jar) but not succeeded.

```
<Channels>
    <Channel>
      <ChannelID IChannelID="bd68786865" />
        <TimePeriod StartTime="2015-04-14T07:00:00" EndTime="2015-04-15T07:00:00"  EndRead="98790.53" />
          <Readings>
            <Reading Value="0.212" >
              <ReadingStatus>
                <UnencodedStatus SourceValidation="xyz" />
              </ReadingStatus>
            </Reading>
            <Reading Value="0.123" >
              <ReadingStatus>
                <UnencodedStatus SourceValidation="xyz" />
              </ReadingStatus>
            </Reading>
         </Readings>
     </channel>
  </channels>
```

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Readings>
```

tag is not closed, therefore your XML is invalid

Comment: it is the self closed tag.It is valid.

Comment: Readings is not a self closed tag

Comment: Ohh Sorry I missed it.It got closed after </Reading>.

Comment: Then you may update your question as your XML sample is wrong and you provided no detail.

Comment: Hi glefait I am more focused on the output part how to extract  the required values.Lets consider that  xml as valid one.However I have modified that.